# jface swt InputDialog with multiple lines

Tags: java, swt, jface

How can I change the Text control style with SWT.MULTI

I tried overriding the method but still the same

```
@Override
protected int getInputTextStyle() {
    return SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the layout on the dialog's text control to set a suggested height. To do this you will need to override `createDialogArea` and change the layout. Something like:

```
@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
  Control result = super.createDialogArea(parent);

  Text text = getText();  // The input text

  GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false);
  data.heightHint = convertHeightInCharsToPixels(5); // number of rows 
  text.setLayoutData(data);

  return result;
}

@Override
protected int getInputTextStyle() {
  return SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@Override
protected int getInputTextStyle() {
    return SWT.MULTI | super.getInputTextStyle();
}
```

Comment: But the size of the control is still same

Answer (score 0):

For multiple line try this :

```
@Override
protected int getInputTextStyle() {
return SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP |  SWT.V_SCROLL
 }
```